# sql server password reset

Tags: sql

I have deleted my windows account on wich I had installed sql server 2008 express. Now I can not perform any operation with my sql server including adding new user.

Pleas sombody help me.

Comment: In such situation using SA credentials is more helpful take a look on this post http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/fix-microsoft-sql-server-login-failed-error-18456/

Answer (score 3):

Log in using SA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [User Provisioning Tool for SQL Server 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/120215/user-provisioning-tool-for-sql-server-2008)